# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when opening Javascript files

Tags: javascript, crash, visual-studio-2015

Every time I open a Javascript file with Visual Studio 2015 Pro RTM it crashes and restarts. No error messages.

I did a repair but I haven't tried uninstalling and reinstalling yet. 
Is anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. It does have something to do with the _references.js file.

> I had to clear out my _references.js file. After I had cleared out the contents of that file, visual studio would no longer crash when opening up javascript files.

This does work but you could lose your some of your intellisense in javascript. 
The issue occurs when I opened a js file that was not included in the _references.js file if there are entries in there. All I had to do is right click the _references.js file and click "Update Javascript References" and it worked fine.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: This seems to have been reported to Microsoft, but they stated they couldn't reproduce it.... https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1749105/visual-studio-2015-crashes-when-working-with-javascript-files

Comment: This saved my life. Almost lost full 24 hours of valuable time because of this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I had to clear out my _references.js file.  After I had cleared out the contents of that file, visual studio would no longer crash when opening up javascript files.

Answer (score 2):

Try to disable any 3rd party stuff, in an attempt to find the culprit that might be causing the problem.  For instance, CodeRush, ReSharper, Web Essentials, etc.  You can find all the ones you have installed under TOOLS->Extensions & Updates.  Then look at the ones in the INSTALLED list.  Disabling them doesn't uninstall them. You can always re-enable them again. You might have to do a few iterations of restarting Visual Studio during this endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

try to  clean cache of VS `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\[version]\ComponentModelCache` or find other cache places

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I have just installed it and barely started using it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem went away for me after creating a new .js file, and then opening the file I actually wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

I no longer use Visual Studio for TypeScript or JavaScript development. I use Visual Studio Code and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

f you click Debug button in the error pop windows, could you get any error message?

Tools->Options->Text Editor, could you see the JS editor there?

Maybe you could disable the option "Auto list members" under JS Editor, and then test it again.

[image]

If not
Delete the .suo file and re-open and rebuild the proj file.

See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c847199f-289a-4fc6-ac0a-600100a29742/vs-2015-crashes-when-editing-a-js-file?forum=visualstudiogeneral) link.